# android unable to create media player

Tags: android

i don't get to run mediaplayer on android when using setDatasource with context and uri.

well, i have this musicplayer service which does:

```
Uri uri = result.get(0).getURI();
String uri2Path = uri.getPath();
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.setDataSource(uri2Path);
//Prepare async playing of media, mediaplayer.start() is called in onPrepared override
mPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

i also tried to set Datasource with both path as String and

```
mPlayer.SetDataSource(this.getApplicationContext(), uri);
```

setting with context and uri i'm receiving a ioException and logcat shows "unable to create media player", when i set datasource with string i get a Error (1, -2147483648) from MediaPlayer.
setting a hardcoded path "sdcard/test.mp3" works well.

i'm receiving mediafiles through android.provider.MediaStore and save them in a List. 
AudioItem resolves the Uri:

```
public class AudioItem
{
    long id;
    String artist;
    String title;
    String album;
    long duration;

    public AudioItem(long id, String artist, String title, String album, long duration) {
        this.id = id;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.title = title;
        this.album = album;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public long getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public Uri getURI() {
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
    }
}
```

when watching uri to play in debugger, it seems like a valid uri "content://media/external/audio/media/12" to me, what could my mistake?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look on Logcat. In my case, I have to insert two permission:

> android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>   android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS

Answer (score -2):

here is a similar example try to download and import it.

[RandomMusicPlayer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/RandomMusicPlayer)

Comment: Dead link.  This is also not an answer.